# Typescript object keys type with recursive subobject adresses, like mongoDb filter

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, typescript-typings

Let's say I have a model:

```js
type MyModel = {
  string: string
  subObject: {
    subObjString: string
  }
}
```

I would like to have a type so all those tests passes:

- ✅ `{ string: 'foo' }`
- ✅ `{ subObject: { subObjString: 'foo'} }`
- ✅ `{ 'subObject.subObjString': 'foo' }`
- ❌ `{ 'subObject.notExistingprop': 'foo' }`
- ❌ `{ notExisting: 'foo' }`

My goal is to type a filter input for a mongoDb ORM where filters can be written with classic and dotted syntax.

My first attempt was to get the keys type right, so here is what I have done so far:

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=92&pln=3&pc=1#code/LAKFBcE8AcFMAIBiBLANuWAnAKjWAeAeXlgA8MA7AEwGd4AlWAYwHtMr8bxNkKBzADTwAhhUgA%20cfAC88AN6h4S%20AG0A0vF7wAFAGtYkFgDN4xAGTwuPfgEoAugC5T6uyXKxqdRq3aduvQRExKQB%20eA0ySlpLSABbACMWVHgwilgANyx4JwADABI5NQBfADoClHQsXDgicSKc7Pg0zMxQIpUrALtQHpAoOHgAWUhBlipYZNkFECVO-ic5vkVLAFd4wniAK2ZwJ2nlVfWtgGV-ecszpZn4Irbe-oQKjBw8RDZR8cmkNGfqgmGPhMpAB6YGaCjPaCYWAYKgiOgrCi6CgsADuFF6rAoXHgGC4AEYZKoAOSLYlCUlrDbbJjgYmuGjCcDIGhGZCwOhPKqvd5jCbwUGWAAWLBWqDhqLYulAWJxePAACYiSpKUcaeASjQqSdLvTLEyWWyOd9Ki84G9MIDkoKaCKxRKpTKWNjwLiOeAAMzK1XUnYlFHgACipBZzP4AAVMCxoHrGczWezOT9uebeZ8BWDjnbxU0WK7JZhdEA)

```js
type FilterType<O extends Record<string, any>> = {
    [K in (keyof O & string)]: O[K] extends Record<string, any> ? K extends symbol ? never : `${K}.${FilterType<O>}` : never
}[string]


type MyModel = {
  string: string
  subObject: {
    subObjString: string
  }
}

type FilterTypeForModel = FilterType<MyModel> // interpreted as unknown

const test1 = ['string', 'subObject'] satisfies FilterTypeForModel // should work
const test2 = ['subObject.subObjString'] satisfies FilterTypeForModel // should work
const test3 = ['subObject.notExistingProp'] satisfies FilterTypeForModel // Should not work
```

Comment: Should `{ parent: { child: 0 }, "parent.child": 1 }` be valid then...?

Comment: @katniss Yes  it can be ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to get all possible paths from an object as a union type:

```js
type DottedKeys<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: 
  K extends string 
  ? T[K] extends object 
  ? K | `${K}.${DottedKeys<T[K]>}`
  : K
  : 'none'
}[keyof T]

type MyModel = {
  string: string;
  subObject: {
    subObjString: string;
    subObj2: {
      string3lv: string
      number3lv: number
    }
  };
};

// ObjectAllPaths contains all possible paths
type ObjectAllPaths = DottedKeys<MyModel> // "string" | "subObject" | "subObject.subObjString" | "subObject.subObj2" | "subObject.subObj2.string3lv" | "subObject.subObj2.number3lv"

// Paths Test cases
type Test1 = 'string' extends ObjectAllPaths ? true : false; // Should be true
type Test2 = 'subObject' extends ObjectAllPaths ? true : false; // Should be true
type Test3 = 'subObject.subObjString' extends ObjectAllPaths ? true : false; // Should be true
type Test4 = 'subObject.notExistingProp' extends ObjectAllPaths ? true : false; // Should be false
type Test5 = 'notExisting' extends ObjectAllPaths ? true : false; // Should be false
```

To go further, as you said that you need that type to be an object finally, here is my attempt to provide an object version:

```js
type OnlyDotted<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: 
  K extends string 
  ? T[K] extends object 
  ? `${K}.${DottedKeys<T[K]>}`
  : never
  : never
}[keyof T]

type AsFilter<T extends Record<string, any>> = Partial<{
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Record<string, any> ? AsFilter<T[K]> : T[K]
} & { [key in OnlyDotted<T>]: any }>

type FilterModel = AsFilter<MyModel>

const modelFilter: FilterModel  = {
    "subObject.subObjString": true, // ✅ dotted path ❌ failed type validation here, need to be improved
    subObject: {
        "subObj2.string3lv": true, // ✅ recursive dotted path ❌ failed type validation here, need to be improved
        subObj2: {
          string3lv: 'string', // ✅ normal path
          number3lv: true //  ✅ should error, type validation working
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** this is not perfect since as you see in comments all dotted paths are typed as any. I couldn't find a better solution for now

**[Here is an updated typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAehFpK6dv+qEACAggGXcg8gIQFICiAwgCrIAKqpAEgMpIJPNPDAAuAngA4CmyAEQD27drwAmAaV6cAzgB5SAPmQBeZAG9gyZAG1JyAJYA7ZAGsZQgGbJSAXQBcybcgO8AHmOPjZyWewAnEwBzZx0Aflt9O2QPLx9kIQAjACteAGN2MORIgwAfZAADABINSQBfADpS4VEJaTlFaKVywpcnSXbkY14AN14A4HLdC05rWzs2Lj5kAFlOWaFxXgAbNU0XfyDjYKctkIBuTYBXJOxUjPYnLR0dWVPzlLpAkL2XnaPbvwfUgCZrlxffY7ADMK16b22wUBt2MxwAtkkBmCId0EUjBl9yi5ykdcWwwDgLplUCsVhQAIbsAAWvnSQmM7ApJl8FLJyG4QlkskMSRW-G4VNpHB4-Eel1J5KFvnUtTEUhkCnmi2WKyUBJQlJpvlIvH8yHSFNkepFM11-gAjOsAOTA4LW2KeXjeXziklkrW0nLIQLHfhOKxs40HZCEujUoTHFbiZBIn0BP2m-jm9i-G33M7E9gOuLOhJu9iSz2+SK+-3IQMrYOhlDhyPR2P8MtJ2x69gg9M-NKZSoZx7PKE5p0uondwse6XesvIANB3ghsMRqMxuPN6bJtsAFk7mbHlWMIkI7kM-hCFACQm4Q-irqzRcnpYT5cr1cX9ZX-BfvBbKYArDaD3YI8T3YEJrzzW8x3vbUpyfGcKznBdayXBs4y-DUWEwrDwCQZAADEAEl0FIQgACUcAIEhSFwmkTyMVlTBMLwsnYIRkHhCkLGQClTGSMdkAAdyEAIzEEwwaW4slcM5bleX5DlJyNBSYJ4mNxBEeVlOFQlSGpfgOJMA0KX6KlkD0gJ+DomlTPUuoY0FGD1L1boRFwiymUMmleEMAJkF6Nk-R9UVuO8biLKCvgYyUnjOEYbD4vgKZguwYwVk4OUJEUFR1BuPQDEM0ZxnsJwXDcYcEjtbJIlIaJHRvRIsyqopSgqaoNAyhVGhqyQ7BaNodCcHp+kxeChoGIYRksGx7CSmZUFkPDDBWMQAkUOqIOQUiMmE8R5DtAAaELOCUbLKApAJQLZeRcv0IxTEK6bHCiHr1pHLb6QCXaDqOlRInmxbloGJoepUJxusmcpkAAMk0PRRjunBUvSjTMuUJ6YuQcp1RbAGVpVVZ1n+paVvkZUllWbH6WMfV4XJlZcYGJwGYCfG1nWXKdAAIj7LNey7AcQk5pwy0OwlAFByZBbM0hzqWQQAZcgQpaJAi-h-JWQxxCpQwGTMgZeEOnpldYxsjHhbgL36cQYR5scAS+L5ua7X5e3eYIUSF+M-VFlAJYs9JjgCHl+kllH7KFeXFf5GN1z8tkNa1nXzP17peCNti40MM2LYkGEgSdu37aBV2UScW1Xetb3kAlg8Ag4tYZdz+24URZFwWFuDCSrvwUJjAYLwCQ6Y7V+PQJ1oSRJCRudGxLEhiAA)**